# Trying to connect to Digital Ocean Kubernates Cluster - .kube/config: not a directory

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I'm trying to connect to a Digital Ocean Kubernates cluster using doctl but when I run
`doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save <>` I get an error saying .kube/config: not a directory. I've authenticated using doctl and when I run `doctl account get` I see my account info. I'm confused as to what the problem is. Is this some sort of permission issue or did I miss a config step somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl` (by default) stores a configuration in `${HOME}/.kube/config`. It appears you don't have the file and the command doesn't create it if it doesn't exist; I recommend you try creating `${HOME}/.kube` first as `doctl` really ought to create the `config` file if it doesn't exist.

`kubectl` facilitates interacting with multiple clusters as multiple users in multiple namespaces through the use a tuple called 'context' which combines a cluster with a user with a(n optional) namespace. The command lets you switch between these easily.

After you're done with a cluster, generally (!) you must tidy up its entires in `${HOME}/.kube/config` too as these configs tend to grow over time.

You can change the location of the `kubectl` config file using an environment variable (`KUBECONFIG`).

See [Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20kubectl%20looks%20for,setting%20the%20%2D%2Dkubeconfig%20flag)